# c++ FLTK (more buttons with the same callback function)

Tags: c++, fltk

I've just joined this amazing community to get an answer for a terribly annoying problem.
I am trying to create a five in a row game with FLTK. Currently I am just finshing its dumber version the tic tac toe.
So my problem is:
I create a board from many buttons. for tic tac toe, the board is only 9 buttons. but for the five in a row it is 15*15 so it is 225 buttons. The real problem starts when i have to define all the callback functions. So is there a way to have only one callback function for all of them? Can I assign a value for buttons so the callback function knows which button was pressed when it calls the callback? 
thank you very much for anyone who reads it :)

**EDIT**

So I tried to go one step further and save all the pointers to the buttons in a vector.

```
vector <Fl_Button *> pointerVec;


/////////the button grid for the board ///////
        int counter = 0;
        int width = 50, height = 50;
        int rowmax = 15, colmax = 15;

        for (int rr = 0; rr < 3; ++rr) {
            for (int cc = 0; cc < 3; ++cc) {


            Fl_Button* bgrid = new Fl_Button(cc * width+80, rr * height+80, width - 5, width - 5);
            int rowcol = counter;

            pointerVec.push_back(bgrid);   //save pointers to the buttons


            bgrid->callback(_playerMove_cb, (void*) rowcol);

            counter++;
            }
        }

////////

//then I tried to pass the vector to a callback function by reference

getAi->callback(getAI_cb, (void*)&pointerVec);


///////
    static void getAI_cb(Fl_Widget *w, void *client) {

    vector<Fl_Button*> &v = *reinterpret_cast<vector<Fl_Button*> *>(client);

    // i wanted to do this //

    v[1]->color(FL_RED);


}
```

So, when i do this, the program crashes. I printed out the memory addresses of the 2 vectors and they were on a different address.
Is there something I am doing wrong?
The reason I want to do this because I would like to color the buttons where the computer player made a move.

Comment: The first parameter of the callback is the Widget and the second is a void*.  If you store userdata in the button, the callback can extract this to work out which button it is.  Let us know if you need an example.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. If you don't mind could you give me a small example? thank you very much

Comment: Re your edit: it looks like you're getting corruption somewhere.  Is the address of w the same as getAI?  If it isn't then something else is calling the routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.  You can pass anything as a parameter.  Just make sure it isn't transient otherwise when the callback comes to getting it, it could end up walking all over the stack or heap.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

void ButtonCB(Fl_Widget* w, void* client)
{
    int rowcol = (int)client;
    int row = rowcol >> 8;
    int col = rowcol & 255;
    std::cout << "row " << row << "  col " << col << std::endl;
}
void CloseCB(Fl_Widget* w, void* client)
{
    std::cout << "The end" << std::endl;
   exit (0);

}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int width = 60, height = 25;
    int rowmax = 5, colmax = 5;
    std::list<std::string> tags;

  Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(colmax * width + 20, rowmax * height + 20);

  for (int rr = 0; rr < rowmax; ++rr)
  {
      for (int cc = 0; cc < colmax; ++cc)
      {
          std::ostringstream lab;
          lab << "R" << rr << "C" << cc;
          // Need to keep the strings otherwise we get blank labels
          tags.push_back(lab.str());
          Fl_Button* b = new Fl_Button(cc * width + 10, rr * height + 10, width - 5, height - 5, tags.back().c_str());
          int rowcol = rr << 8 | cc;
          b->callback(ButtonCB, (void*) rowcol);
      }
  }
  window->end();
  window->callback(CloseCB, 0);
  window->show(argc,argv);
  return Fl::run();
}
```

Comment: I tried to go one step further with your example, If you have some time could you have a look at it? I edited the main post. thank you:)